# Set Python Logging to Azure Blob, but Can not Find Log File there

Tags: azure, logging, flask, azure-blob-storage

I'm setting up logging on a flask service. I  tried to write logs to an azure blob storage with the following code

```
import logging
import sys

from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'service.log', 
                                                    account_name='servicestorage',
                                                    account_key='',
                                                    maxBytes= maxBytes,
                                                    container='service-log')
azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)
```

Then, I tried with logger.warning('test warning'), but there's not log file created on the azure blob container.

Can anyone help me figure out where I did wrong?

Best,
Eigen

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Comment: Thanks for your following. I figures out that the azure blob I first tried is for China market. The logging works when I connect to  global azure blob. Any way to point the logging handler to azure blob in China market?

Answer (score 5):

I tried your code in my flask but did't reproduce your issue.

***code:***

```
@app.route('/log')
def log():

    import logging
    import sys
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

    mystorageaccountname='***'
    mystorageaccountkey='***'

    logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
    azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'service.log', 
                                                        account_name=mystorageaccountname,
                                                        account_key=mystorageaccountkey,
                                                        maxBytes= 5,
                                                        container='service-log')
    azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
    logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)

    logger.warning('warning message')
```

***output:***

[image]

More details, you could refer to the [doc](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/) and [source code](https://github.com/michiya/azure-storage-logging/blob/master/tests/tests.py).

Hope it helps you. Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: there is problem that it does not upload if the content does not reach till maxBytes. And irrespective of size it should not upload results after logging ends.